# GenStaticText on MS Windows: does it support markup?

Tags: wxpython

If I understand [wxPython docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Control.html#wx.Control.SetLabelMarkup) correctly, this part:

> Currently wx.Button supports markup in all major ports (wxMSW, wxGTK and OSX/Cocoa) while wx.StaticText supports it in wxGTK and wxOSX **and its generic version (which can be used under MSW if markup support is required)**. Extending support to more controls is planned in the future.

state that `GenStaticText` should support markup on MS Windows? Reading [this thread](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=47010) also implies that?

My code does not reproduce that:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.stattext import GenStaticText


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Example'

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel,1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Center()
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ST = GenStaticText(self, label='', style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.ST,1,wx.EXPAND)

        self.ST.SetLabelMarkup("<b>Bold text</b>")

        self.SetSizer(sizer)


app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

Is there an error? Is there any way to get `GenStaticText` or `wx.StaticText` to support markup on MSW?

Answer (score 0):

on **wx.StaticText** one can **SetFont(font)**

Comment: Yeah, but it's not the same functionality. Markup could theoretically support different styles for different words within the same label.

Comment: then **HTML**, it dwarfs any Markup

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).